# Flutter bloc listener not listening to state changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am using flutter_bloc library to create a verification code page. Here is what I tried to do.

```
class PhonePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static Route route() {
    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => PhonePage());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) =>
            ValidationCubit(context.repository<AuthenticationRepository>()),
        child: PhoneForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhoneForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<ValidationCubit, ValidationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        print('Listener has been called');
        if (state.status.isSubmissionFailure) {
          _showVerificationError(context);
        } else if (state.status.isSubmissionSuccess) {
          _showVerificationSuccess(context);
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Container(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  _HeaderAndTitle(),
                  _VerificationInput(),
                  _VerifyButton()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showVerificationError(context) {
    Scaffold.of(context)
      ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Validation error')));
  }

  void _showVerificationSuccess(context) {
    Scaffold.of(context)
      ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
      ..showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Validation Success'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ));
  }
}

...

class _VerifyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ValidationCubit, ValidationState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
      return RaisedButton.icon(
          color: Colors.blue,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 38.0, vertical: 12.0),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          icon: state.status.isSubmissionInProgress
              ? Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.ellipsisH)
              : Icon(null),
          label: Text(state.status.isSubmissionInProgress ? '' : 'Verify',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
          onPressed: state.status.isValid
              ? () => context.bloc<ValidationCubit>().verifyCode()
              : null);
    });
  }
}
```

Now the verifyCode() function is an async function defined inside ValidationCubit. It emits states with status set to loading, success and failure. However the listener doesn't pick up those changes and show the snackbars. I couldn't figure why? I am also using the Formz library as suggested in the flutter_bloc documentation. Here is the verifyCode part.

```
Future<void> verifyCode() async {
    if (!state.status.isValidated) return;
    emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionInProgress));
    try {
      // send validation code to server here
      await _authenticationRepository.loginWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: 'email@email.com', password: '12');
      emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionSuccess));
    } on Exception {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: FormzStatus.submissionFailure));
    }
  }
```

The verification code model looks like this:

```
class ValidationState extends Equatable {
  final VerificationCode verificationCode;
  final FormzStatus status;

  const ValidationState({this.verificationCode, this.status});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [verificationCode];

  ValidationState copyWith(
      {VerificationCode verificationCode, FormzStatus status}) {
    return ValidationState(
        verificationCode: verificationCode ?? this.verificationCode,
        status: status ?? this.status);
  }
}
```

And the validation state class is:

```
class ValidationState extends Equatable {
  final VerificationCode verificationCode;
  final FormzStatus status;

  const ValidationState({this.verificationCode, this.status});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [verificationCode];

  ValidationState copyWith(
      {VerificationCode verificationCode, FormzStatus status}) {
    return ValidationState(
        verificationCode: verificationCode ?? this.verificationCode,
        status: status ?? this.status);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what bloc states there are. I know that 'listner' is triggered when state is changed from another state..

Comment: is it printing         print('Listener has been called'); ??

Comment: please add your State class or States that you have defined.

Comment: @xbadal I have updated it to include the state and the model classes. It's not printing the "Listener has been called" when the button is clicked.

Comment: you are not yielding state. so basically state is not changing. this is why its not printing.

Comment: But this is cubit. I thought that's why we are emitting.

Comment: I am pretty confident that your problem is the props property of the state. Can you add the status property to the props of your state, and try again ? The listener is called only when the state is changing and because you use the Equatable you have to let it know all your mutable properties in order to tell a state is really equal to another. `@override
  List<Object> get props => [verificationCode, status];`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the problem is your state class.

> listener is only called once for each state change (NOT including the initial state) unlike builder in BlocBuilder and is a void function.

Every time when a new state is emitted by the Cubit it is compared with the previous one, and if they are "DIFFERENT", the listener function is triggered.

In you situation, you are using Equatable with only `verificationCode` as `props`, which means when two states are compared only the `verificationCode`s are tested. In this way BLoC consumer thinks that the two states are equal and do not triggers the listener function again.

If you check your `verifyCode()` function the only changing parameter is `status`.

In order to fix that add the `status` property to the `props` list in your state class.

```
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [this.verificationCode, this.status];
```

Comment: thank you bro. I was getting a different issue. but your answer helped me

Comment: What if I want to listen to the previous state itself and do something in the listen method?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to update same state just add one state before calling your updating state
like this
if you want to update 'Loaded' state again call 'Loading' state before that and than call 'Loaded' state so BlocListener and BlocBuilder will listen to it

**Edited**
I have changed using bloc to cubit for this and cubit can emmit same state continuously and bloclistener and blocbuilder can listen to it

Comment: Please share some short sample code in your answer

Comment: try using cubit it can emmit same state and bloclistener and blocbuilder can listen to it

Comment: This is fake news. Cubit behaves the same was a bloc with regard to emitting states. If you emit exactly the same state, it will not be heard by  the listener.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue as well. I realized I needed to move my BlocBuilder further up the widget tree so that I could listen to a context with an active Bloc.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete a list item from the list and app should pops a pop-up before delete. Somehow you decline the delete pop up via no button or click outside of the pop-up, last state doesn't change. After that, if you want to delete same item, it wasn't trigger cause all parameters are same with the previous state and equatable says its same. To get rid of this issue, you need to define a rand function and put just before your emit state. You need to add a new parameter to your state and you need to add to the props. It works like a charm.

My state;

```
class SomeDeleteOnPressedState extends SomeState
    with EquatableMixin {
  final int index;
  final List<Result> result;
  final String currentLocation;
  final int rand;/// this is the unique part.

  SomeDeleteOnPressedState({
    required this.index,
    required this.result,
    required this.currentLocation,
    required this.rand,
  });
// don't forget to add rand parameter in props. it will make the difference here.
  @override
  List<Object> get props => <Object>[index, result, currentLocation, rand];
}
```

and my bloc;

```
on<SomeDeleteEvent>((event,emit){
int rand =Random().nextInt(100000);
 emit(
            SomeDeleteOnPressedState(
              currentLocation: event.currentLocation,
              index: event.index,
              result: event.result,
              rand: rand,/// every time it will send a different rand, so this state is always will be different.
            ),
          );

});
```

Hope it helps.